# Concavity of decreasing $C^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose I have a decreasing $C^2$ function $\psi:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$. I would like to prove it is concave on its domain, i.e. that:

$$\psi(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \geq \alpha \psi(x) + (1-\alpha)\psi(y) \quad \forall \alpha \in(0,1), \quad x,y \geq 0$$

Suppose $\psi(0)=0$. Can we use the assumed decreasing property to just restrain ourselves to verify the above inequality when we fix $y=0$ (the below inequality)?  That is, for such functions $\psi$ is it true that the below condition is sufficient to verify their concavity? My intuition suggests this is true, but I can't seem to prove it.

$$\psi(\alpha x) \geq \alpha \psi(x) \quad \forall \alpha \in(0,1), \quad x > 0$$

Comment: Wording of the question should have been a lot better.

Comment: @geetha290krm I think the question is perfectly intelligible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\psi(x) = x(e^{-x}-1)$. Note that $\psi(0) = 0, \psi'(x) \le 0$.

If $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then $\psi(\alpha x) = \alpha x(e^{-\alpha x}-1) \ge \alpha x(e^{-x}-1) = \alpha \psi(x)$, but
$\psi''(x) = (x-2) e^{-x}$, which is positive for $x>2$.